# colorWithPatternImage vs CGImage vs UIImageView

Tags: ios, ios7

I've seen on many forums that you shouldn't use colorWithPatternImage for memory issues, you should use UIImageView if you are using a large background image and add as a subview to save memory. I tried with these three solutions and all of those are showing same memory used:

```
// First Option
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background"]];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView];

//Second Option
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background"];
self.view.layer.contents = (id) image.CGImage;

//Third Option
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background"]];
```

I am using iOS7 SDK. Is there anything I am missing or have iOS7 improved in this direction?